# Uploadify shows completed but no file in directory

Tags: php

I am using uploadify for file uploading.
It's showing progress and completed but when I look into the directory there is no file uploaded

Here's my code:
**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Uploadify Implementation</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="uploadify/uploadify.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="uploadify/jquery.uploadify.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'swf'      : 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : 'uploadify/uploadify.php'
        // Your options here
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" />
</body>
</html>
```

**uploadify.php**

```
<?php
// Define a destination
$targetFolder = '/uploads'; // Relative to the root

$verifyToken = md5('unique_salt' . $_POST['timestamp']);

if (!empty($_FILES) && $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken) {
$tempFile = $_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
$targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

// Validate the file type
$fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
$fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['file_upload']['name']);

if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    echo '1';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid file type.';
}
}
?>
```

Here's a screenshot of my FTP directories
[image]

Comment: Use Google Chrome (unsure about other browsers), when you try to upload something do you see a 'Uploading' message at the bottom left-hand corner of your screen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uploadify- operations completes, but no upload is made](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585527/uploadify-operations-completes-but-no-upload-is-made)

Comment: And you're getting the `1`'s you're echoing, no errors (you did turn on error reporting), and you're sure you have write access.

Comment: @cybermonkey i see no uploading message in the left-hand corner of the screen when uploading.

the console however returns this 

"Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://error.hostinger.eu/?". "